# Showing that a Krylov subspace is invariant under A

Tags: linear-algebra

A is a symmetric positive definite matrix and I am trying to show that $S_K$(A,**v**)=span{**v**,A**v**,...,$A^{k-1}$**v**}.

To do this I have said let **z** belong to $S_K$(A,**v**). Then, **z**=$a_1$**v**+$a_2A$**v**+$a_1$$A^2$**v**+...+$a_k$$A^{k-1}$**v**

So I need to show A**z** belongs to $S_K$(A,**v**), so:
A**z**=$a_1A$**v**+$a_2$$A^2$**v**++...+$a_k$$A^{k}$**v**. Clearly the first k-1 terms belong to $S_K$(A,**v**) so it suffices to show that $a_k$$A^{k}$**v** belongs to $S_K$(A,**v**).

I am assuming I need to express $A^{k}$ in terms of lower powers, but I am unsure how to do this. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Let's see now, is $A$ a $k\times k$ matrix? Note that $\{v, Av, ..., A^{k-1}v, A^kv\}$ contains $k+1$ vectors and (assuming $A$ is $k\times k$) must be linearly dependent (too many vectors, since they all are $k$-dimensional). $A^kv$ must then lie in the span of the other vectors, by linear dependency.

Comment: Sorry I  forgot to write that A is n X n where n>k.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then my argument doesn't work. Do you have any restrictions on $k$, other than $k<n$?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What is $S_K(A,v)$? What is the relation between $k$ and $K$? Are you trying to show that $S_K(A,v)$ is $A$-invariant?

Answer (score 0):

If $A\in \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$, you can use the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) to express $A^k$ as a linear combination of $I$, $A$, ..., $A^{k-1}$, which, in turn, implies that $A^k v \in S_K(A,v)$.